# Why can't I access Flask API through load balancer on AWS

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, elastic-load-balancer

I deployed a Flask app with Gunicorn on EC2 instance via port 8080. Now I want to set up a load balancer to enable SSL and link to a domain eventually. The swagger page can be accessed by `http://ec2-dns:8080/api`. A classic type of load balancer is created with the EC2 added. Health Check is good. But when I tried to hit the endpoints using the load balancer's dns name `https://lb-dns/api`, it would time out with 408.

Why is it not working with the load balancer?

Comment: Can you verify:
If CLB Port listeners are configured for incoming ports of HTTPS 443 to forward to instance port HTTP 8080? you can first check with non https. Eg: Map 80 to 8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you listener should be looked like this 
[image]

also check the security group has the right port opening